# Cant Run Google appengine python app on eclipse although launcher works fine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-python-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/

I created a project and tried to run it locally. It didn't work but when I ran it on the Google appengine launcher it worked just fine.

I noticed that eclipse doesn't create .project and .pydevproject files in the project

here is the console contents:

```
WARNING  2012-11-28 07:48:10,265 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
Invalid arguments
Runs a development application server for an application.

dev_appserver.py [options] <application root>

Application root must be the path to the application to run in this server.
Must contain a valid app.yaml or app.yml file.

Options:
  --address=ADDRESS, -a ADDRESS
                             Address to which this server should bind. (Default
                             localhost).
  --clear_datastore, -c      Clear the Datastore on startup. (Default false)
  --debug, -d                Use debug logging. (Default false)
  --help, -h                 View this helpful message.
  --port=PORT, -p PORT       Port for the server to run on. (Default 8080)

  --allow_skipped_files      Allow access to files matched by app.yaml's
                             skipped_files (default False)
  --auth_domain              Authorization domain that this app runs in.
                             (Default gmail.com)
  --backends                 Run the dev_appserver with backends support
                             (multiprocess mode).
  --blobstore_path=DIR       Path to directory to use for storing Blobstore
                             file stub data.
  --clear_prospective_search Clear the Prospective Search subscription index
                             (Default false).
  --clear_search_indexes     Clear the Full Text Search indexes (Default false).
  --datastore_path=DS_FILE   Path to file to use for storing Datastore file
                             stub data.
                             (Default c:\users\gideon\appdata\local\temp\dev_appserver.datastore)
  --debug_imports            Enables debug logging for module imports, showing
                             search paths used for finding modules and any
                             errors encountered during the import process.
  --default_partition        Default partition to use in the APPLICATION_ID.
                             (Default dev)
  --disable_static_caching   Never allow the browser to cache static files.
                             (Default enable if expiration set in app.yaml)
  --disable_task_running     When supplied, tasks will not be automatically
                             run after submission and must be run manually
                             in the local admin console.
  --enable_sendmail          Enable sendmail when SMTP not configured.
                             (Default false)
  --high_replication         Use the high replication datastore consistency
                             model. (Default false).
  --history_path=PATH        Path to use for storing Datastore history.
                             (Default c:\users\gideon\appdata\local\temp\dev_appserver.datastore.history)
  --multiprocess_min_port    When running in multiprocess mode, specifies the
                             lowest port value to use when choosing ports. If
                             set to 0, select random ports.
                             (Default 9000)
  --mysql_host=HOSTNAME      MySQL database host.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default 'localhost')
  --mysql_port=PORT          MySQL port to connect to.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default 3306)
  --mysql_user=USER          MySQL user to connect as.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default )
  --mysql_password=PASSWORD  MySQL password to use.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default '')
  --mysql_socket=PATH        MySQL Unix socket file path.
                             Used by the Cloud SQL (rdbms) stub.
                             (Default '')
  --persist_logs             Enables storage of all request and application
                             logs to enable later access. (Default false).
  --require_indexes          Disallows queries that require composite indexes
                             not defined in index.yaml.
  --search_indexes_path=PATH Path to file to use for storing Full Text Search
                             indexes (Default c:\users\gideon\appdata\local\temp\dev_appserver.searchindexes).
  --show_mail_body           Log the body of emails in mail stub.
                             (Default false)
  --skip_sdk_update_check    Skip checking for SDK updates. If false, fall back
                             to opt_in setting specified in .appcfg_nag
                             (Default false)
  --smtp_host=HOSTNAME       SMTP host to send test mail to.  Leaving this
                             unset will disable SMTP mail sending.
                             (Default '')
  --smtp_port=PORT           SMTP port to send test mail to.
                             (Default 25)
  --smtp_user=USER           SMTP user to connect as.  Stub will only attempt
                             to login if this field is non-empty.
                             (Default '').
  --smtp_password=PASSWORD   Password for SMTP server.
                             (Default '')
  --task_retry_seconds       How long to wait in seconds before retrying a
                             task after it fails during execution.
                             (Default '30')
  --use_sqlite               Use the new, SQLite based datastore stub.
                             (Default false)
  --port_sqlite_data         Converts the data from the file based datastore
                             stub to the new SQLite stub, one time use only.
                             (Default false)
  --[enable|disable]_console Enables/disables the interactive console.
                             (Default enabled if --address is unset,
                              disabled if --address is set)
```

Comment: Your project setup is wrond, because the log states in cannot find an app.yaml. Try it again and don not use the use src: “Create ‘src’ folder and add it to PYTHONPATH“.

Comment: I have a source folder and the PYTHON path leads to it can you be more specific?

Comment: You can use it, but do not need it and my experience is : it makes the project environment harder to use. Without the src you can run and debug your project from the project folder instead of the src folder.

Comment: I tried creating a project without src folder and running it I'm getting the same error

Comment: The src folder is not the problem. Explain how you run the project, because the log says that your dev_appserver.py runs without or wrong options.

Comment: right click on the project/.py file -> project name and main module C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py -> arguments tab -> program argument ${project_loc}/src
–port=8889 -> working directory default ${project_loc:/selected project name} -> run

Comment: I still see /src. But I use: right click project and select option: Run as --> PyDev: Google App Run

Comment: Thank you VOSCAUSA your hint kind of lead me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 run configurations that I managed to run the project localy with.

1. right click project --> Python Run
   in main tab 
   Project text field browse to project
   In Main Module path to appserver C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py
   in Arguments tab
   Program arguments "${project_loc}/src" make sure you put the ""

in Working directory check Other ${project_loc:/selected project name}

bellow
apply
run

1. right click project --> PyDev Google App Run
   in main tab 
   Project text field browse to project
   In Main Module path to appserver ${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/dev_appserver.py
   in Arguments tab
   Program arguments "${workspace_loc:HelloWorld/src}" make sure you put the "" 
   in Working directory check Other ${workspace_loc:HelloWorld}

next time you can just click the configuration

To upload to the cloud appengine run configurations.

right click project --> PyDev Google App Run
in main tab 
    Project text field browse to project
    In Main Module path to appserver ${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/appcfg.py
 in Arguments tab
    Program arguments update "${workspace_loc:HelloWorld/src}" 
make sure you put the "" 
make sure update is outside the ""
in Working directory check Default ${project_loc:/selected project name}

To whom it might concern an IDE should shield the developer from the Idiosyncratic nature of the command line I spent 7 hours trying to run a project using faulty tutorials