# How to debug with persistent local NDB data in Eclipse / Python / Appengine?

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm developing a Python app for AppEngine using Eclipse / Pydev and need to debug with persistent data stored in the local NDB.

Now, the default path for the NDB on my Linux machine is /tmp and this gets discarded after each reboot. I couldn't find a way to tell Eclipse to use a custom path for the NDB, so I finally resorted to starting the dev_appserver.py via the terminal with:

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/home/myfolder/workspace/myapp_datastore app.yaml
```

Now when I start the debugger I really need persistent data to trace some tricky bugs, but as mentioned, I couldn't find a way to tell eclipse where to store the local NDB so as a consequence I can't use the debugger with persistent data.

Anybody knows a solution?

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm a PyCharm, not an Eclipse user, the answer is based on info I saw.

A `Run Configuration` window with an `Arguments` tab allowing you to configure optional arguments for `dev_appserver.py` is mentioned in the (rather old) [Cant Run Google appengine python app on eclipse although launcher works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600267/cant-run-google-appengine-python-app-on-eclipse-although-launcher-works-fine/13640485#13640485), but confirmed in [4.4. Run your application](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleAppEngine/article.html#eclipse_run):

> You still can use the command line to run your GAE application. But we
>   are now going to configure Eclipse to allow you to run your
>   application directly from Eclipse. Right-click on "todo.py", select
>   Run As ▸ Run Configuration. Under Main Module maintain the path to
>   dev_appserver.py.
>
> [image]
>
> Switch to the argument tab and maintain the full path name of your
>   project as a parameter. Put the parameter in double-quotes.
>
> [image]

I agree, these are `Run Configurations` and you're asking about configuration for debugging the app. Well, at least in PyCharm they apply to running through the debugger as well, they're actually called `Run/Debug Configurations`.

Maybe the same applies to Eclipse as well, so IMHO it's worth to locate this tab in your Eclipse version and configure in it the arguments you desire, then check if they apply in the debugger.

Comment: Hi Dan,

Thanks for the tip. However, I couldn't get it to work on eclipse :-(

In eclipse I have the same tabs as you have but I haven't found a way to insert the parameter "--datastore_path=/home/myfolder/workspace/myapp_datastore" or to define a path to the datastore.

Rgds

Philip

Comment: Change `"${project_loc}/src"` (or whatever you have) to `-datastore_path=/home/myfolder/workspace/myapp_datastore "${project_loc}/src"`?